# Swift coding multiple tableviews- how to connect them up?

Tags: uitableview, swift

Hi I'm new to coding so basically i've created a tableview app on github 
the first one shows what i want to do without code https://github.com/edlen/guideline.git
and the second one is an attempt to recreate it with code
https://github.com/edlen/guidelines-via-code.git

but I'm really stuck about how to create code for going between screens so say for example on the main menu I select helpful info, how do i make the tableview with those options appear? and then if i select PO switch how do I segue to it?

Technically I can do what I want grand without code but I would really like to be able to understand coding of tableviews better and how to go between multiple tableviews and then select a final individualised view controller full of text.

Any advice that you could offer would be great- but please be prepared to speak very slowly and clearly as I'm still learning as i go along!!

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials around the internet, I'm not sure if I'm allowed to post some links here. Just check google or youtube for "UITableViewController tutorial" or something like that, I'm sure you'll find what you need. If you have some more detailed questions, I can help you. But that's pretty much to explain how to create UITableViews with code.

Comment: thanks beeef unfortunately the tutorials are all based around obj c and i'm having trouble finding a good one for translation of it to swift if that makes sense? I have been looking at the tutorials on youtube but drawing a blank most stop after just one tableview- they don't deal with multiple tableviews unfortunately

Comment: OK I'm trying to post a short tutorial for you here. Just wait a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, designing the app with Interface Builder inside Xcode is both the same for Swift and Objective C.

A UITableViewController should be embedded inside a UINavigationController, if you want to switch between views. Just drag'n'drop a UINavigationController and a UITableViewController into your storyboard - make sure the *UITableViewController* is the root viewcontroller of the navigation controller (right-click drag the tableview controller on the navigation controller).

After that, create a new Cocoa Touch Class - file (or press CMD-N). Look at this:
[image]

**Make sure you choose *UITableViewController* at "Subclass of".**

---

After that, go back to your interface builder and select your UITableViewController. There go to the identity inspector to change the class of your tableview controller. Look here:

[image]

---

After that, you just need to choose a reuse identifier for you tableview cells. You need the reuse identifier, so that your iPhone (or iPad) can reuse a cell and doesn't have to create a new one everytime. I just chose "myCell" as reuse identifier. To do that, click on the cell and go to the attributes inspector:

[image]

---

OK, the part with interface builder is done. Now go to your previously created *MyTableViewController.swift*.

There you have some methods. You need at least these to methods:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

and

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

You need these methods, because the data source of your tableview is set to *self*. That means, this class is used to fill your tableview with information. 
Let's start simple. To test everything, just use 1 section. So in your *numberOfSectionsInTableView* return 1.

If you have some data to be displayed, I think you'll store this data inside an array? However, in *numberOfRowsInSection* you have to return the number of rows that have to be displayed inside that section. So if you want to display 3 rows, just return 3 here. That makes **1 section** with **3 rows** inside that section.

---

Now you have to customize your tableview cell with labels and maybe an image view. So you need the function

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    // add some UILabels or UIImageViews here.

    return cell
}
```

to create your own cells. Here you'll need the reuse identifier you've set in interface builder.

---

A UITableView also has a delegate, which is responsible for events like (de)selecting a cell. So if you want to show a UIViewController when the user taps on a cell, you have to implement the method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Here you can switch between views. Here you need to have the tableview controller embedded inside a navigation controller (except you are presenting your views as modal view controllers, but that's not the point here).

So the user taps on a cell, you have the index of the cell inside *indexPath.row* - you'll need that to show the user the information inside the new view. After that, create your UIViewController or whatever, and present the viewcontroller with

```
self.navigationController?.presentViewController(myViewControllerToPresent, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
        // some code to do after the presentatioin is ready
    })
```

That's it!

Comment: Thank you very much!!!    I do have another question if that would be ok ? "UITableView also has a delegate, which is responsible for events like (de)selecting a cell. So if you want to show a UIViewController when the user taps on a cell, you have to implement the method

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath"    How does this work? hypothetically speaking is it possible to have two arrays in the view controller.swift? and then is it this method allowing me to switch between them? I guess this is the part I'm most stuck on- how to segue between

Comment: that means clicking the tick beside your answer right? No problem!

Comment: Thanks!
No, if you want to switch between table views, you need to have two table view controllers. If you want to show another tableview controller when you tap on a cell, you need to present that second view controller.

Comment: and what is the specific line of code for switching when a cell is selected? e.g. if you have a tableview (animaltableviewcontroller) with cat, dog and snake and you select the row dog what code lets you switch to (dogbreedviewcontroller) displaying labrador, collie, boxer ? Oh and also is it necessary to create a new cococa class for each individual tableview controller like i did in the second github example?

Comment: If you don't want to work with interface builder, you can create UITableViewControllers programmatically, but I don't recommend that. Just create a UITableViewController with interface builder, a Cocoa Touch Class file and connect them. After that, right-click drag from a cell to the second tableview controller and give that segue an identifier. Then, in didSelectRowAtIndexPath just use "self.performSegueWithIdentifier("switchToDogSegue", sender: self)". Just try a little bit.

Comment: thank you! I'll have a go and see how it goes! fingers crossed!